# How can I get an array to present cleaner?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a form that I created that I want to populate certain sections of a bit of pre-written code with the inputs from the form.

The Javascript is as follows

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
    if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
        if (!o[this.name].push) {
            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
        }
        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
    } else {
        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
    }
});
return o;
};

$(function () {
$('form').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var oo = $('form').serializeObject();
var template = '<center><a href="{url}" target="_blank" onclick="cmCreateCustomTag(\'8888\',\'-_--_--_--_--_-____{name}_{bannerposition}_{trigger}-_-Pers_MNT_{name}_-_--_-\' + new Date().toISOString() + \'-_-\');" ><img src="{imgsrc}" alt="{alt}" title="{title}"></a></center>';

$('#result').text(
    template.replace(/{url}/g, oo["URL"])
                .replace(/{name}/g, oo["name"])
                .replace(/{trigger}/g, oo["trigger"])
                .replace(/{bannerposition}/g, oo["banner_position"])
                .replace(/{imgsrc}/g, oo["image_src"])
                .replace(/{alt}/g, oo["alt"])
                .replace(/{title}/g, oo["title"])
    );
});
```

Here is the [entire code in a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfisherjr/Eu4cy/).

I have included what the final form should look in the commented out section at the bottom of the code. How do I insert the data so that I can use the data quickly?

Comment: Insert the data where?

Comment: You want to make the output visually easier to read? Or you want to access individual values within the JSON?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you want to do. The fiddle you posted is working, showing the serialized output of the form when you submit the form. Please be more specific in what you want to get.

Comment: I'm trying to get the array to present inside of the a pre-built set of HTML in the commented-out section below, (in the fiddle), where just the input from the form will be inserted inside of the html.

I'm trying to get it to live inside of the html that was written. I can't get the array to append inside, where it needs to go.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What commented-out section? I'm not seeing one: http://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfisherjr/CDqZ8/

Comment: I'm sorry I just realized I did not update the fiddle with the commented out section. It's there now. Sorry about that.

Comment: When you update a JS Fiddle demo, it'll generate a new URL. You'll need to update the link in your question to show us that updated demo (assuming you remembered to save it).

Comment: I just put the new fiddle demo up with the commented out section. Thanks for being patient with me, I can imagine how hard it is dealing with a newb.

Comment: Nelson, no problem being a newb ;) This site is awesome, but for being like that it has very strict rules. And they relate more to research and clarity on you formulation, not how much you know. Check the guides [ask] and [About]. Bem-vindo à bordo!

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured I was poking a bear asking a simple question but I just don't know the right questions to ask.  At this point I'm amazed I got this far. Thanks for being cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited the above code as well but this is the way I found to present the array inside of my specific code based on user input.  Thank you everyone for your help. :)

Here is the [entire code in a JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfisherjr/Eu4cy/).

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function(){
var o = {};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function() {
if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
    if (!o[this.name].push) {
        o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
    }
    o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
} else {
    o[this.name] = this.value || '';
}
});
return o;
};

$(function () {
$('form').submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var oo = $('form').serializeObject();
var template = '<center><a href="{url}" target="_blank" onclick="cmCreateCustomTag(\'8888\',\'-_--_--_--_--_-____{name}_{bannerposition}_{trigger}-_-Pers_MNT_{name}_-_--_-\' + new Date().toISOString() + \'-_-\');" ><img src="{imgsrc}" alt="{alt}" title="{title}"></a></center>';

$('#result').text(
template.replace(/{url}/g, oo["URL"])
            .replace(/{name}/g, oo["name"])
            .replace(/{trigger}/g, oo["trigger"])
            .replace(/{bannerposition}/g, oo["banner_position"])
            .replace(/{imgsrc}/g, oo["image_src"])
            .replace(/{alt}/g, oo["alt"])
            .replace(/{title}/g, oo["title"])
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to "pretty print" it you can use something like this:

```
  $(function () {
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var res = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());
    //Puts a line break after each comma
    $('#result').html(res.replace(/([,\{\}])/g, function (match) {
        if (match == "," || match == '{') {
            return match + "\n";
        } else {
            return "\n" + match;
        }
    }));
  });
});
```

#### [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/raam86/CDqZ8/4/)

Comment: I'm trying to get that to work but it will not display the array. I've tried several ways to implement it I just can't get it to work. What am I missing here?

Comment: Yes the edit made it work. Thank you.  I am trying to get the array to append to the commented out code at the bottom of the fiddle, (please note the new url for the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nelsonfisherjr/L8tKy/). Sorry for being unclear before.  Your method definitely makes it look "Prettier".

Comment: @nelsonfisherjr what do mean append? So it will be written inside the center tag? simply replace  $('#result') with $('CENTER_ELEMENT_ID)'

Comment: Append is the obviously the wrong word here.Each specific item in the form has a corresponding section in the code and I want it to display the code with the form answers inserted in them.

Comment: <center><a href="id=URL" target="_blank" onclick="cmCreateCustomTag('8888','-_--_--_--_--_-____'id=name'_'id=banner_position'_'id=trigger'-_-Pers_MNT_'id=name'_-_--_-'+new Date().toISOString()+'-_-');" >
<img src="'id=img_src'" alt="'alt'" title=""></a></center>

Comment: So the output should have the id=** filled in based on the input from the form.